# For which $f \in \mathbb{C}[x,y][T]$, all irreducible elements of $\mathbb{C}[x,y]$ remain irreducible in $\mathbb{C}[x,y,T]/(f)$

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, ac.commutative-algebra, polynomials

Let $f=f(T) \in \mathbb{C}[x,y][T]$ be a monic polynomial:
$f=T^n+a_{n-1}T^{n-1}+\cdots+a_1T+a_0$,
$a_j \in \mathbb{C}[x,y]$.

Denote: $A=\mathbb{C}[x,y]$ and $B=\mathbb{C}[x,y,T]/(f)=\mathbb{C}[x,y][w]$,
where $w^n+a_{n-1}w^{n-1}+\cdots+a_1w+a_0=0$.

Of course, $A$ is a UFD, so irreducible elements of $A$= prime elements of $A$.

> Can one describe all possible forms of $f$, for which every irreducible element of $A$ remains irreducible in $B$?

The motivation to ask this question is 
$k[x^2] \subset k[x^2][x^3]$; it seems that every irreducible element of $k[x^2]$ remains irreducible (but not prime) in $k[x^2][x^3]=k[x^2,T]/(T^2-(x^2)^3)$.

**Remarks:** 
(1) Notice that $a_0$ is reducible in $B$.

(2) I assumed that $f$ is monic in order to obtain that $A \subset B$ is flat,
according to Nagata's theorem, [Theorem D.2.2](https://books.google.co.il/books?id=wKJqqd8t8KUC&pg=PA293&lpg=PA293&dq=nagata%20flat&source=bl&ots=5cPyiVY9iO&sig=Po6z7y7C7Hs6AEDg08FW21fLr3M&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwighZjWm7TUAhUHBsAKHf0jAZUQ6AEIMjAD#v=onepage&q=nagata%20flat&f=false) ($e=1$). Actually, $A \subset B$ is free.

(3) A plausible answer can be found in [Lemma 3.2](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1601.01508v1.pdf) which says the following:
Let $A$ be a UFD. Let $R \subseteq A$ be a subring of $A$ such that 
$R^* = A^*$.
The following conditions are equivalent:
(i) Every irreducible element of $R$ remains irreducible in $A$.
(ii) $R$ is factorially closed in $A$, namely, if $x,y \in A$ satisfy 
$xy \in R - {0}$, then $x,y \in R$; however, in my question, the smaller ring is a UFD, while in Lemma 3.2 the larger ring is a UFD.

I guess that my question has no complete answer, so partial answers are also welcome. 
Thank you very much!

Comment: Here is a possible negative answer. If $B$ is a UFD, then $n$ must be one.

Comment: Thanks. I did not claim that every irreducible element of $A$ must remain irreducible in $B$; I only asked for a general form of $f$ that guarantees this.

Comment: Anyway, since you raised the point of $B$ being a UFD (which I did not assume): Can you describe a general form of $f$ for which $B$ is a UFD?

Comment: Interestingly, this ($B$ is a UFD) is true for all sufficiently `general' $f$ if $n\geq 4$, by a theorem called Noether-Lefschetz from algebraic geometry. So, to get a non-UFD, you have to take special $f$.

Comment: For your earlier comment, basically I am saying that in general this is never true unless $A=B$ ($n=1$). So, you can only expect special $f$ to get what you want, if at all.

Comment: The Noether-Lefschetz theorem sounds very interesting! thank you very much! Please can you give a reference for it.

Comment: See Griffiths and Harris-Algebraic Geometry.

Comment: Thanks!! (I think I will ask now a similar question to the above, about when $B$ is a UFD).

Comment: If I am not wrong, an example of a 'special' $f$ is: $f=T^2-xy$. Indeed, $x$ and $y$ are still irreducibles in $B$ (and it seems that every irreducible of $A$ remains irreducible in $B$).

Comment: @Mohan, please, is it possible to apply the results of https://arxiv.org/abs/alg-geom/9305001 on my above question, in a similar way you have applied Noether-Lefschetz theorem? Thank you.

Comment: @Mohan, please, could you take a look at https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3548048/application-of-nother-lefschetz-theorem#3548048? Thank you